# Getting information from image

Tags: c, image-processing

I  need to develop an application that needs do some image-processing. Assume the illustrative image:

[image]

I'm looking for *how* get answers to the following questions:

1. How do I determine how many circles there's in this specific part of
   image?
2. And its colors?

See the number `1.` in the image, it means first "line" of image where can have several circles. I need to get all.

So, my question is:

What do I need to know to be able to develop such application? books recomendation will be very appreciated.

Some information:

- The original image format (image-input) is PNG or JPEG.
- The circles positions(including spaces among them) are static.
- I'm looking for the howto, to then make the algorithms, but if there's a library that does well the job, I may use too.

Comment: Q: Have you looked at OpenCV?

Comment: @paulsm4: Thanks. I don't knew about this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long answer: Digital Image Processing by Gonzalez & Woods is the book you want to read. There's everything & more you need for this task :)

The short answer: If your background is white & homogeneous and stays that way then it's a manageable (if not easy) task. You start with region growing of pixel clustering, which means that you try to find the groups of pixels that are (i) interconnected and (ii) different from the white background. Then you go for the color the majority of the pixels have in each cluster (medoid, not median), which would give you the circles' colors.

Pixel clustering can be done on color is there are homogeneous patches, then split the pixels of the same color by a connected components approach.

As the comment above said OpenCV will help you a lot.

Comment: How hard is done it without OpenCV? Also, I'm going to get this book.

Comment: Without OpenCV I mean with help of the book

Comment: Basically it's not too complicated. You'd first apply a segmentation algorithm to find the patches in the gray value image. You can do this with flood fill for instance, or MSER. Then you can go for the central point of each segment and check if it is a circle by counting the pixels outside a perfect circle overlay. Then you'd need to investigate the color within the circles' centers and you are there.